# window.cordova.plugins is always undefined in Ionic on Telerik AppBuilder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, telerik, cordova-plugins, telerik-appbuilder

I'm not sure I made the right decision to create an Ionic application in Telerik App Builder. I am almost done with the app, but I have one super-frustrating issue I have had for the past week or so. I have added `ngCordova` to my application, so that I can use `$cordovaClipboard`, which allows a device to copy text to the clipboard. In my controller I do a

```
console.log($cordovaClipboard)
```

and I get the definition of the `copy(text)` and `paste()` methods in this service/object. However, when I call the `copy(text)` method of the `$cordovaClipboard`, I get

> ng-cordova.js:1819 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clipboard' of undefined.

I have tried using the ready function of the `ionicPlatform` service and the `deviceready` event of the DOM but I will always get undefined. It seems `cordova` plugins are not working or do not work well with Telerik AppBuilder or Ionic or a combination.

Please assist.

Comment: Anyone please??? I am on the verge of deleting my app and starting all over again

Comment: Are you using the simulator, a physical device, or an emulator when this happens?